# Get Full size profile picture from linkedin api

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I have a login with linkedin Script, i want to fetch the original size of the linkedin user profile picture when i write picture-url it provide me with 24*24 px image that is unsuitable for my website. According to linkedin docs and other stack overflow i found i need to pass picture-urls::(original) below

```
  $success = $client->CallAPI( 
                'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,location,picture-url,public-profile-url,formatted-name)', 
                'GET', array(
                    'format'=>'json'
                ), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
}
}
  $success = $client->Finalize($success);
 }
 if ($client->exit) exit;
 if ($success) {
$user_id = $db->checkUser($user);
$_SESSION['loggedin_user_id'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}
```

After adding picture-urls::(original) it looked like this->

```
$success = $client->CallAPI( 
            'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,location,picture-urls::(original),public-profile-url,formatted-name)', 
            'GET', array(
                'format'=>'json'
            ), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
}
```

But no Picture was resulted after this